# How to solve linking pdfium on windows 10

Tags: windows, gcc, linker, pdfium

I have the main.cpp on Windows at C:\repo\pdfium\out\debug\obj\test  directory. Pdfium.lib is at obj directory.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fpdfview.h>
int main() {
FPDF_InitLibrary();
FPDF_DestroyLibrary();
printf("PDFium hello.\n");
return 0;}
```

pdfium.lib is build with GCC(is_lang=false)

With command i am producing main.o

> g++.exe -std=c++11 -g -I........\public -c
> C:\repo\pdfium\out\debug\obj\test\main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o

With command bellow i am trying to link pdfium.lib

```
g++.exe  -o bin\Debug\test.exe obj\Debug\main.o   ..\pdfium.lib
```

But i am taking ...

```
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
..\pdfium.lib(obj/core/fpdfapi/parser/parser/fpdf_parser_utility.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$?_Makestr@_System_error@std@@CA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@2@Verror_code@2@V32@@Z]+0x8): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
```

I have try so many time but nothing on linking on windows 10.
Any advice will be redemptive.

Thank you

Jim

Comment: I have been trying to build pdfium with MinGW-w64 under MSYS2 and it seems to use `gn` as build tool. I have `gn` on my system, but I can't seem to get it to configure/build the project. How do you build pdfium?

Comment: @BrechtSanders Probably worth asking that in its own question if you're still interested in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're building PDFium with a non-component build (`is_component_build = false` in `args.gn`) and not setting `pdf_is_complete_lib = true`, the generated `.lib` files won't have their dependencies included, so you're quite likely to have the linker complain about missing symbols. Try either generating DLLs (`is_component_build = true`) or setting `pdf_is_complete_lib = true`.

If you use a component build, you'll need to package the PDFium DLL and its dependencies (at least the `zlib` DLL, possibly others) with your application.